# Drop rows that has text values based on condition

Tags: python

I have data frame called mastersheet that like below:

```
Band     RSRP
Band 1    -98
Band 3    -76
Band 1    -87
Band 1    -95
Band 3    -94
```

I would like drop all rows that contain the word Band 1
so output will have only rows that is equal to Band 3
Any idea how I can code it in python?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Band': ['Band 1', 'Band 3', 'Band 1', 'Band 1', 'Band 3']})

# Solution
df = df.drop(df[df['Band'] == 'Band 1'].index)
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Now if i had drop a blank entry in a row do i write the below: df=df.drop(df[df['Band'] == ''].index)

Comment: It depends on the values, if value is `''` then your code is good. When the value is `np.nan`, you may use `isnull()` or `dropna() following the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73311068/19523606

Answer (score 0):

Use `.loc` with a conditional statement: `df["Band"] != "Band 1"`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Band': ['Band 1', 'Band 3', 'Band 1', 'Band 1', 'Band 3'],'RSRP': [-98,-76,-87,-95,-94]})

df
     Band  RSRP
0  Band 1   -98
1  Band 3   -76
2  Band 1   -87
3  Band 1   -95
4  Band 3   -94
```

```py
df = df.loc[df["Band"] != "Band 1"]

df
     Band  RSRP
1  Band 3   -76
4  Band 3   -94
```

For blanks, you can use a `.loc` as well, with a conditional such as `~df["Band"].isnull()`, or you can use `dropna`

Using `dropna`

```py
df = df.dropna(subset=["Band"])
```